# How do I calculate the work done in a vector field across a line segment?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, curl

> Let C be the line segment from $(2, 3, 0)$ to $(5, 7, 9)$ followed by the line segment from $(5, 7, 9)$ to $(1, 1, 2).$ Consider a force field
> $F(x, y, z) = <3x^2+yz+y,xz+x+z^2,xy+2yz+2z>$

> Calculate the work done by $F$ on a particle taking the path $C$.

How would I solve this? Here's what I have so far:

Calculating the curl for the force field, I get = $(0,0,0)$ which means it's conservative. So I know then the integral must be:

$$\int _CF\cdot \:dr\:=\:f\left(1,\:1,\:2\right)-\:f\left(5,\:7,\:9\right)$$

Taking their respective partial derivatives I get:

$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(3x^2+yz+y\right)$

$\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(xz+x+z^2\right)$

$\frac{\partial \:}{\partial \:z}\left(xy+2yz+2z\right)$

$$f(x,y,z)=6x+2y+2$$

So my final answer is:

$$\left(6\left(1\right)+2\left(1\right)+2\right)-\left(6\left(5\right)+2\left(7\right)+2\right)=-36$$

Is this the right process and answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

It is a conservative vector field but the potential function you have set up is not correct.

The Potential function is $f(x,y,z) = x^3 + xyz + xy + (y+1)z^2$.

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 3x^2 + yz + y$ which is part of your vector field. You can check other partial derivatives similarly.

One way to find the potential function is take the first component ($i$) of the vector field and integrate wrt $x$, similarly take the second component ($j$) wrt $y$. From there on, you should get the function.

Pls take only the end points for your calculation $(2, 3, 0)$ to $(1, 1, 2)$ because the integral will be path independent.

Comment: oh so I integrate instead of differentiate! thanks i got chu now. so 2,3,0 would be my first point then? I see thanks